# Filter firebase data by logged in user REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created an app using react and firebase for backend. I have fully working code to authenticate users, they can register and login successfully. They can as well create "cards" on the front end and they get stored on the firebase realtime database. I would like to only display (filter) Cards created by users to be able to be seen only by the user that created it. Right now all and any cards created by users are visible to all users.

Here's how i am adding Cards to the firebase DB, i'm just not sure how to filter by UID:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const cardRef = firebase.database().ref('Cards')
    cardRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const cards = snapshot.val()
      const cardslist = []
      for (let id in cards) {
        cardslist.push({id, ...cards[id] })
      }
      setCardslist(cardslist)
    })
  },[])
```

Here is the full project which you can fork and edit:
https://codesandbox.io/s/firelog-lpfe5?file=/src/Hero.js:1942-2241

Comment: There is documentation for filtering queries in Realtime Database.  I suggest starting there to make an attempt.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: it doesn't mention anything about filtering by users. Does that matter/?

Comment: You have to know what child you're filtering for.  The database doesn't know anything about users, just the data that you added to it.  You have to connect the dots to make a query for the user data you want.

Comment: At first glance none of the properties in the JSON of your database are UIDs, so it'll not be possible to filter on a UID value. In order to be able to filter on a value, that value must be present in the JSON.